# Access XML Attribute Names in Extendscript

Tags: javascript, xml, attributes, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I'm trying to parse an xml Object in extendscript and especially deal with the Attributes. I know i can access xml attributes by

```
xmlObj.@attributename
```

and

```
xmlObj.attributes()
```

returns a list of all attributes, but I also need the attribute names not just the values. Is there anyway to get something like and associative array/object with names and values?

(I use extendscript for illustrator CS6)

thank you,
arno

Answer (score 2):

The code below should get you going. Take also a look into the [XMLElement Object](http://yearbookmachine.github.io/esdocs/#/InDesign/XMLElement).

```
var main = function() {
  // create some xml and write it to file
  var root = new XML("<root/>");
  var child = new XML("<child/>");
  child.@string = "Hello Attribute"; // jshint ignore:line
  child.@num = 23; // jshint ignore:line
  root.appendChild(child);
  var file = new File("~/Desktop/test.xml");
  var xml = root.toXMLString();
  file.open("W");
  file.write(xml);
  file.close();

  // get the current doc
  var doc = app.activeDocument;
  // import the xml
  doc.importXML(file);
  // get the elements
  var xmlroot = doc.xmlElements[0];
  var xmlchild = xmlroot.xmlElements[0];
  // loop all attributes of element "child"
  // and write them into the console
  for (var i = 0; i < xmlchild.xmlAttributes.length; i++) {
    var attr = xmlchild.xmlAttributes[i];
    $.writeln(attr.name);
  }
};
main();
```

Comment: Thank you,
unfortunately I forgot to say that I use Extendscript for Illustrator (cs6), the script only worked in inDesign. Is there a way to handle it with illustrators XML Class?

Comment: No problem. I took a look around but did not find any good solution. I think it could be done by using xPath expressions.

Comment: I tried it with xpaths, but somehow they don't work in extendscript.
name(//element/@*[1])  works in any xpath evaluater but in extendscript it returns nothing

Comment: Strange isn't it? Maybe you ask at the Adobe forums. I would still go for the [InDesign Scripting forum](https://forums.adobe.com/community/indesign/indesign_scripting). They are the most active and often have to deal with xml

Answer (score 0):

i've found a way solve it with regular Expressions

```js
function getAttributes(xml_node_str) {
  // select the start tag <elem >
  var reg_exp = /<[^>]*>/;
  var start_tag_str = reg_exp.exec(xml_node_str);

  // extract the attributes
  reg_exp = /[^"\s]*="[^"]*"/g;
  var result;
  var attributes = [];

  while ((result = reg_exp.exec(start_tag_str)) !== null) {
    // the attribute (name="value")
    var attr = result[0];
    // array containing name and "value"
    var attr_arr = attr.split('=');
    // delete the "'s
    attr_arr[1] = attr_arr[1].substr(1, attr_arr[1].length - 2);

    attributes.push(attr_arr);
  }
  return attributes;
}
```

I still parse the xml with Extendscripts/Illustrators xml-class and then extract the attributes manually

```js
var xml = <root><obj a1="01" a2="02" ></obj></root > ;

var attributes = getAttributes(xml.obj.toXMLString());

for (var i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
  alert(attributes[i][0] + ' -> ' + attributes[i][1]);
}
```